# Every time I run chef-client, it downloads JDK which take 5 min. How to skip?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Even time I run chef-client on a box it waits around 5 minutes to download the JDKs even though it has done it before. Is there any way to go around this?

```
[Mon, 22 Oct 2012 13:17:46 -0500] INFO: Processing remote_file[/var/chef/cache/jdk-1.6-u30-linux-amd64.rpm] action create_if_missing (sun_java::default line 18)
[Mon, 22 Oct 2012 13:17:48 -0500] INFO: Processing package[jdk-1.6-u30-linux-amd64.rpm] action install (sun_java::default line 25)
[Mon, 22 Oct 2012 13:21:07 -0500] INFO: package[jdk-1.6-u30-linux-amd64.rpm] installed version 1.6.0_30-fcs
[Mon, 22 Oct 2012 13:21:07 -0500] INFO: package[jdk-1.6-u30-linux-amd64.rpm] sending run action to bash[update-alternatives java] (immediate)
[Mon, 22 Oct 2012 13:21:07 -0500] INFO: Processing bash[update-alternatives java] action run (sun_java::default line 40)
```

The recipe is as below:

```
urlVersion = "1."+node["sun_java"]["version"].sub(/[u]/, "-u")
node.default["sun_java"]["rpm_url"] = "http://***/#{urlVersion}/jdk-#{urlVersion}-linux-#{node["sun_java"]["arch"]}.rpm"

#Check that we are using the .rpm file because of the recent change
if File.extname(File.basename(node["sun_java"]["rpm_url"]))!=".rpm"
  raise "You must use the jdk*.rpm file to install the Sun JDK. You can get it from the jdk*-rpm.bin file by running the command './jdk*-rpm.bin -x'"
end

javaRPM = File.basename(node["sun_java"]["rpm_url"])

remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{javaRPM}" do
  action :create_if_missing
  source node["sun_java"]["rpm_url"]
  mode "0755"
  backup false
end

package javaRPM do
  action :install
  source "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{javaRPM}"
  options "--nogpgcheck" # sun/oracle doesn't sign their RPMs o_O
  notifies :run, "bash[update-alternatives java]", :immediately
end

javaHomeFolder = "/usr/java/jdk1.#{node["sun_java"]["version"].sub(/[u]/, ".0_")}"
jdkFolder = "#{javaHomeFolder}/bin"
slaveString = ""

node["sun_java"]["update_slaves"].each do |java_bin|
  slaveString = slaveString + "--slave \"/usr/bin/#{java_bin}\" \"#{java_bin}\" \"#{jdkFolder}/#{java_bin}\" "
end

bash "update-alternatives java" do
  action :nothing
  code <<-EOH
    update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "#{jdkFolder}/java" 1 #{slaveString}
    update-alternatives --set java #{jdkFolder}/java
  EOH
end

#Remove old environment then notify new environment to be created
ruby_block "delete_environement" do
        block do
            editBashrc = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/profile")
                editBashrc.search_file_delete_line(/^.*#JAVA_HOME environment settings.*$/)
                editBashrc.search_file_delete_line(/^.*#Auto-generated by Chef Cookbook sun_java.*$/)
                editBashrc.search_file_delete_line(/^.*export JAVA_HOME=.*$/)
                editBashrc.write_file 
        end
        action :create
end

#create environment of root user
execute "create_environment" do
  user "root"
  command "echo -e '#JAVA_HOME environment settings\n#Auto-generated by Chef Cookbook sun_java\nexport JAVA_HOME=#{javaHomeFolder}' >> /etc/profile"
end
```

Comment: Judging from the timestamps, it seems like it takes Chef 2 seconds to download the package. This makes me wonder if it indeed re-downloads it every time...

Comment: Also, could you please paste the relevant portion of the recipe here?

Comment: @awendt: I have updated the question with the recipe. Have also updated the logs to show its not 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the download that takes 5 minutes. It seems like rpm is re-installing the package every single time (output shortened and commented):

```
[Mon, 22 Oct 2012 13:17:46 -0500] Processing remote_file # Download the file
[Mon, 22 Oct 2012 13:17:48 -0500] Processing package # Install the file 2 secs later
[Mon, 22 Oct 2012 13:21:07 -0500] package installed # 3+ minutes later
```

I don't know about `rpm`, but Debian's package management skips already installed packages by default.

So I guess your options are:

1. Configure chef to be more verbose. That way, you can trace the calls with all options and see if you re-produce the behavior by running the same commands from a shell.
2. Find out if `rpm` behaves the same way as Debian `dpkg` (see above). If not, tell it to skip packages that are already installed.
3. Check the package versions. If your package version is the same on every run, go to (1). If it's not, find out if you can get `rpm` to skip similar versions.
4. Don't use the `package` resource but rather install the package by hand (use only if all other options fail). For example, you could use the [`execute` resource](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Execute) and create an indicator file that tells Chef you already installed the package.

Pseudo code for option #4:

```
execute "install Java by hand" do
  command "rpm install <pkg> && touch /home/user/java_installed"
  creates "/home/user/java_installed"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, am looking out for option 3, if not possible ill skip to 4.

Comment: If you're through, please leave a comment here about your solution. I'm curious :)